# Transforming data in dictionaries into rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file in the following format:

```
id    data
1     [{'name':'Day 1', 'data':[12,13]},{'name':'Day 2', 'data':[34,45]}]
```

and I want it in the format below:

```
id    name     index    data
1     Day 1    0        12
1     Day 1    1        13
1     Day 2    0        34
1     Day 2    1        45
```

I've tried doing pd.apply(Series) on the data column but it only separated the dictionaries into their own columns. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is king of redundant , using `apply(pd.Series)` , couple of times

```
(df.set_index('id').data
   .apply(pd.Series)
   .stack()
   .apply(pd.Series)
   .set_index('name',append=True).data
   .apply(pd.Series)
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
   .drop('level_1',axis=1)
)

   id   name  level_3   0
0   1  Day 1        0  12
1   1  Day 1        1  13
2   1  Day 2        0  34
3   1  Day 2        1  45
```